# Special Configurations on RavenDB Id's

Tags: ravendb

I want to adapt two small things on the Id's of RavenDB, so I execute the following code:

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = (prop) => prop.Name == "ID";
documentStore.Conventions.DocumentKeyGenerator = (entity) => entity.GetType().FullName + "/";
```

But these lines of code only work if the other line is not enabled, I can't get both to work together.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code exactly as you provided and it works in RavenDB 1.0.992.  I think you are using an older version.

Really though, you should be customizing the `FindTypeTagName` convention instead of `DocumentKeyGenerator`.

```cs
documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = prop => prop.Name == "ID";
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type => type.FullName;
```

Comment: Interesting, but that worked in my current version. Thanks a lot!